# Laravel ::all() alternative that returns a Builder object

Tags: php, laravel

I have Models of a specific class, which I would like to filter further by passing a Filter object with conditions into a method that parses it and chains `where`s of different kinds, in the end only returning models that match the filter.

To do so, I want to find a method that is equivalent to calling ::all(), but returns an `Eloquent\Builder` instance, instead of a `Collection`.

```
// Returns Collection
App\Entity\Post::all();

// Returns Eloquent\Builder
App\Entity\Post::query();

// Returns Query\Builder
\DB::table('posts');

/**
 * This method allows you to make complex Eloquent queries based on an existing one.
 *
 * @param Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param App\Entity\Filter $filter
 * @return Eloquent\Builder
 */
function parse_filter(Eloquent\Builder &$query, App\Entity\Filter $filter)
{
    $rules  = $filter->rules;
    $groups = $this->_prepare_groups($rules);
    return $this->_parse_groups($query, $groups);
}

/**
 * @param Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param array   $groups
 * @return Eloquent\Builder
 */
function _parse_groups(Eloquent\Builder &$query, array $groups)
{
    foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
        // chain with previous conditions
        // make Closures using group data
        // run Closures on Query I have so far
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Provide some code of what you have tried?

Comment: @KuldeepMishra I've added some examples above (the functions are my code which I use for chaining the conditional methods Laravel provides, I doubt they matter much in the context of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually call `::query()` statically to achieve these results.
This also might be useful as a substitute of `\DB::table('models')` if for your needs `Eloquent\Builder` is interchangeable, or preferable to `Query\Builder` which is returned by `\DB::table()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your complete requirement But you can try laravel macros

```
Builder::macro(
            'customAll',
            function (App\Entity\Filter $filter) {
                $rules  = $filter->rules;
                $groups = $this->_prepare_groups($rules);
                return $this->_parse_groups($query, $groups);

            }
        );
```

Comment: The original problem I ran into was being unable to use the groups parser on a `Collection` instance. Thanks for the advice about macros though, I could definitely use them for 'static' groups with predefined conditions to avoid "wet" code.